# Hide Python Verbose

Tags: python, chatterbot

I am new to Python development.
I am trying to integrate [ChatterBot](http://chatterbot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html#installing-from-github) in a webpage on my local host.
So to do this my first challenge is to establish a talk between a web page and Python script and I have achieved this.
The issue I am facing is - when I train ChatterBot using a list it shows verbose but I don't want those verbose on the webpage since they are of no use for the end user, so for this I tried **logging.basicConfig** with diifferent-2 logging levels but I am not able to hide logs.

**Here is my webpage (index.html) :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Text Input</h2>

<form action = "chatbot.py" method = "POST" >
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname">

  <button type = "submit" >Submit</button>
</form>

<p>Note that the form itself is not visible.</p>

<p>Also note that the default width of a text input field is 20 characters.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here is chatbot.py**

```
#!C:\Users\Shishupal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\python.exe
# This program prints Hello, world!

from chatterbot import ChatBot
import logging


print("Content-Type: text/html")
print()
import cgi
print('Hello, world!')

logging.basicConfig(logging.INFO)

# Create a new chat bot named Charlie
chatbot = ChatBot(
    'Charlie',
    trainer='chatterbot.trainers.ListTrainer'
)

chatbot.train([
    "Hi, can I help you?",
    "Sure, I'd like to book a flight to Iceland.",
    "Your flight has been booked."
])

# Get a response to the input text 'How are you?'
response = chatbot.get_response('I would like to book a flight.')

print(response)
```

Verbose that comes when I don't put or when I put logging.basicConfig(logging.INFO) in chatbot.py, so I want to hide these logs since they are of no use for end user.

[image]

Is there any Python expert over the Globe who can help me in sorting this out :)

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the verbose output by changing the logging level.

Take a look at this line in your code:

```
logging.basicConfig(logging.INFO)
```

Right now, the logging level is `INFO` which prints everything.

You can choose a less verbose logging level such as `WARNING`, `ERROR`, or `CRITICAL`.

You can also remove the logging configuration line entirely to disable the verbose logging.

Comment: Another option is to tell `logging` to output to a file rather than the CGI output.

Comment: @Gunther For me, Its not working. These logs are coming from Chatterbot i.e a library to debelop chatbot.

Comment: @DanD. Thanks for your reply, But your suggestion would not work in my case since I don't have access of ChatBot class.